# Example of a module $M$ such that $\operatorname{depth}_{\mathfrak p}M<\operatorname{depth}_{A_{\mathfrak p}}M_{\mathfrak p}$; Matsumura, Ex. 16.5

Tags: commutative-algebra

> I am looking for an example of a module $M$, a ring $A$, and a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ such that  $\operatorname{depth}_{\mathfrak p} M < \operatorname{depth}_{A_{\mathfrak p}} M_{\mathfrak p}$. How  can I find such an example?

If $A$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$, and $M = A$, then if $\mathfrak m$ is associated we have $\operatorname{depth}_A M=0$. On the other hand, if I can choose a prime $\mathfrak p$ that is not an associated prime of $A$, we get $\operatorname{depth}_{A_{\mathfrak p}} M_{\mathfrak p} \ge 1$. How can I look for this example?

Let's take $A = k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$. Then $\operatorname{depth}_A A = 0$. Take $\mathfrak p = (y)$. Is it true however that $\operatorname{depth}_{A_{\mathfrak p}} A_{\mathfrak p} \geq 1$?

Comment: No, it is not true that $\operatorname{depth}_{A_{\mathfrak p}} A_{\mathfrak p} \geq 1$ for some obvious reason: $\mathfrak p^2=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Try a similar example for $A$, that is, a quotient ring of a polynomial ring in *three* indeterminates.

Comment: Ok. But is my ring and module correct now? The problem is that the only prime I can see containing $(xy,y^2,z^2)$ is of course $(x,y,z)$ which is maximal. Unless I now take $M =  k[x,y,z]/(xy,y^2,yz)$.

Comment: @Lynn16 Finally you made the right choice for $M$! What $p$ do you suggest now? (BTW, $(y,z)$ also contains $(xy,y^2,z^2)$, and is not maximal.)

Comment: Ok, so $A = k[x,y,z]$, $p = (y,z)$ and $M = k[x,y,z]/(xy,y^2,yz)$. We clearly have $depth_(y,z) M = 0$ since the ideal acts by zero divisors on $M$. When we localize at $M$, $M_{(y,z)} = k[x,y,z]/(xy,y^2,yz)_{(y,z)} =  k[x,y,z]/(y,y^2,yz)_{(y,z)} = k[x,z]_{(z)}$ and so the depth is now greater than or equal to 1 yes?